# Is there any info on the plot for the upcoming 2016 film "Star Trek Beyond" besides what's in the wikia article?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-reboot, star-trek-beyond

There is info on the new *Star Trek* film, *Star Trek Beyond* in [this Wikia article.](https://en.memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Beyond)

Is there any info on any plot info other than what is already mentioned in this article?

Comment: I hope to God we see the Excelsior-class

Comment: Inclined to VTC as opinion-based and too time-localized, but I'm not that guy.

Comment: @ThePopMachine what's opinion based about it? If someone has a link or an interview with an actor or writer discussing the plot that would constitute info on the plot. There's nothing opinion about that. But go ahead and VTC if you think it's appropriate. In fact read Praxis's answer below.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - actually, the mods'll probably close it because it's for a future work that's not out yet.

Comment: @JMFB:   Yes, I agree that it may not be opinion-based, but the consensus seems to be that questions which are related to the state of information at a particular point of time are not on-topic.  (This is sometimes called "too localized" in time, although that reason isn't available on VTC anymore.)   Why?   Because the question is either arbitrary (what was the state of knowledge on 8/1/15?) or the answer keeps changing, which is even worse.   This is not the site for those questions.

Comment: @JMFB:  .... please don't take this the wrong way ... I'm usually strongly against VTCs except for very flawed questions ... but I'm going to VTC primarily because I want to see how the more experienced members will weigh in, and I believe that pretty consistent site policy is that this question "should be" VTC even though no one has done so yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question about future works such that the answer will change over time, or that are isolated to an arbitrary point in time, are generally considered Not For This Site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Memory Alpha entry for *Star Trek Beyond* is up-to-date.  As far as I can tell, there is no further confirmed plot information than what is already in the entry that you link to ***at this time***.

If and when there is new information, one of the places where it might appear first is:

- [TrekMovie.com](http://trekmovie.com)

In the meantime, you can read the following (unsubstantiated) predictions regarding the upcoming film:

- [5 Extremely Accurate Predictions for *Star Trek Beyond*](http://www.tor.com/2015/04/24/5-predictions-for-star-trek-beyond/)

Lastly, in researching your question, I stumbled upon the following pretty big goof-up.  When you enter **"star trek beyond"** into Google, you get the following "plot summary":

[image]

(Obviously, Google hasn't learned to distinguish *Beyond* from *Search for Spock* yet, the trouble being that they are both the "third movie".)

Comment: This Google result is interesting, but maybe it ought to be in a comment?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I thought about doing that.  But I though it would be nice to prominently display what can go wrong when you seek information about the *future*. :-)

Comment: What do you expect?  Google Future™ is still in beta.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Nice.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis good answer, love the google entry at the bottom. +1

Comment: @praxis check out mos

Comment: @praxis they put it on hold but I still was able to award you the correct answer. Thanks for the info and the links. I'll check up on it regularly. I should have just made the question, other than this wikia site, are there other credible places to find out about plot development for the upcoming ST movie...and it probably would have been okay.

Comment: @JMFB : Thanks!  I'm glad I could help.  Like you, I'm very curious about what will happen in *Star Trek Beyond*...

Comment: If you weren't so far away, in another country, lol, I'd go with you. I even have a spock robe and a live long and prosper t-shirt, lol.

Comment: @JMFB : Okay, now that's *awesome*. :-)

Comment: They showed best of both worlds here on a big screen in a theatre along with commentary before and after. It was like three hours of pure heaven. The commentary was great as well. I went in my t-shirt and spock robe. I thought everyone would be dressed but it was like maybe 15%. People loved it though and said if they didn't have to go straight from work they would have gotten dressed up as well. Live long and prosper...

Comment: @JMFB : "Peace and long life." (Sarek would reply with this when people told him "Live long and prosper".)

Comment: @Praxis of course I know that, lol. I wish I could edit your comment. I gave a fairly detailed answer about where that saying comes from amongst other tidbits Jewish, here:http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32002/aside-from-the-vulcan-salute-have-nimoy-shatners-jewish-heritage-had-any-s

Comment: @JMFB : Thanks for the link to that answer, very interesting!  I just +1'ed it. :-)

Comment: @praxis I saw, and thank you. I'm a bit peeved that I wasn't awarded a correct turnaround. I've almost caught the other answer and it had a two year start! Yeah can you believe Spock and Sarek are both Jewish in real life? Like father like son...

Comment: @JMFB : Sometimes it happens that the best answer is not awarded acceptance for whatever reason.  Take this one for example: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94466/why-didnt-dr-pretorius-die Not only does my answer already cover what the other answer covers, mine treats all the possibilities.  Oh well.

Comment: +1 to you we should do this all night, lol. why is there a +250 under your name on that answer? check out this one where I answered my own question, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92328/morally-legally-how-could-dr-bashir-a-federation-doctor-perform-the-operation

Answer (score -1):

Possibly flip response warning:

No.

Aside from the fact this question would probably considered off-topic by many as it is about a future work, I would add that it doesn't appear there's going to be any info on the movie besides what's on https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Beyond because that site is so complete and detailed, that you can bet that any meaningful information will get added to it as it becomes available.

Bottom line:  scifi.SE is not going to be better at answering this question than Memory Alpha.